# Onclick event not working with AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I want to display selected image's slideshow with the help of ajax and to do this fetching of title is very important to display corresponding slideshow but in **JavaScript, title of the clicked image is not fetching.**

**javascript:**

```
function slide(s) {
    var _event = s;
    alert(_event);
}
```

**code:**

```
<div id="inner_body">
    <?php
    $c = mysql_connect("localhost", "abc", "xyz");
    mysql_select_db("root");
    $sql = "select * from images where year=2000";
    $qc = mysql_query($sql);
    $count = 0;
    while ($ans = mysql_fetch_array($qc)) {
        $title = ucwords($ans['event']);
        print " 
            <div class='img-wrap' onclick='slide($title)'>
                <img id='display_img' src='images/thumbnails/$ans[image1]'>
                <div class='img-overlay'>
                    <b1>" . $title . "</b1>
                </div>
            </div>";
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

missing quotes tag

```
onclick='slide($title)'; //render onclick='slide(xxxx)'
//should be
onclick='slide(\"$title\")'; //render onclick='slide("xxxx")'
```

### PS.

image tag must be closed `<image />` or `<image></image>`

`<b1>` is undefined(also `<b></b>` is outdated legacy HTML). this should be `<strong>...</strong>`

Answer (score 0):

pass `this` on onclick and using jquery find child element with class `title` get the value of the html.

**Javascript**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function  slide(s)
    {
        alert($(s).find('.title').html());   
    }
</script>
```

**code**

```
    <div id="inner_body">
    <?php
    $c = mysql_connect("localhost", "abc", "xyz");
    mysql_select_db("root");
    $sql = "select * from images where year=2000";
    $qc = mysql_query($sql);
    $count = 0;
    while ($ans = mysql_fetch_array($qc)) {
        $title = ucwords($ans['event']);
        print " 
            <div class='img-wrap' onclick='slide(this)'>
            <img id='display_img' src='images/thumbnails/$ans[image1]'>
            <div class='img-overlay'>
             <b1 class='title'>" . $title . "</b1>
             </div>
            </div>";
    }
    ?>
</div>
```